# What type of xml element is this?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to add this element in my android app for steps.

But I'm unable to recognize it. Can anyone please tell me that what it is called?

So that I can search for further. Code to add it in application will be much more appreciated.

Thank you..

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check for `PagerTabStrip/PagerTitleStrip`